# Proper way to pass symmetric key using System.Data.SqlClient to SQL Server stored procedure that invokes exec sp_executesql

Tags: c#, recursion, sql-server-2017, encryption-symmetric, system.data.sqlclient

I have a column encrypted by a password-protected symmetric key in SQL Server 2017. On the server I can call `sp_foo` from another stored procedure like this:

```
declare @symkey_password varchar(50) = 'Where would we be without stackoverflow'
exec sp_foo @id, @symkey_password
```

and in `sp_foo` we have this:

```
 create procedure sp_foo
     @id int, @symkey_password varchar(50)
 as
 begin
     set @openkey = 'open symmetric key MY_SYM_KEY decryption by password = ' + quotename(@symkey_password,'''') + ';'
     exec sp_executesql @openkey;

     select name, convert(varchar(100), decryptbykey(myencryptedcolumn)) as plaintext
     from T 
     where id = @id   

     CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY MY_SYM_KEY;   
end
```

That works just fine server-side.

However, client-side, when I pass @id and @symkey_password as standard parameters in a `SqlCommand`, and attempt to use `SqlDataAdapter.Fill`:

```
string pass = "Where would we be.... etc etc";

var c = new SqlCommand();
c.CommandText = "sp_foo";
c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

c.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id",12345);
c.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@symkey_password, SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
c.Parameters["@symkey_password"].Value = pass;

var DA = new SqlAdapter(c);

DataTable T;
DA.Fill(T);
```

sometimes I get the following error:

> maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

and sometimes I get this one:

> The key is not encrypted using the specified decryptor. The key 'MY_SYM_KEY' is not open. Please open the key before using it.

What is the proper way to call a stored procedure client-side in C# when the stored procedure invokes `sp_executesql`?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks.  I actually use "usp" but had no idea that the name affected performance.

Comment: Really interesting question. I'm surprised you can't just parameterize the open; this *feels* like a timing issue around competing open/close; very awkward

Answer (score 0):

you need to open your symetrik key MY_SYM_KEY before all sql statements in your stored procedure

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MY_SYM_KEY
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [your certificate name]
```